# Open MPI program not working when distributing processes among multiple hosts

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing

My test program works fine when I run multiple processes on a single machine.

```
$ ./mpirun -np 2 ./mpi-test
Hi I'm A:0
Hi I'm A:1
A:1 sending 11...
A:1 sent 11
A:0 received 11 from 1
all workers checked in!
```

When I run the same program on multiple hosts the process is spawned on each host, but MPI_Send never returns.

```
$ ./mpirun -np 2 -host A,B ./mpi-test
Hi I'm A:0
Hi I'm B:1
B:1 sending 11...
```

I've tried a couple other sample MPI programs I found and I ran into the same problem. Any idea what is going wrong?

EDIT: this also runs on a remote machine if all the processes are spawned on that machine.

Code:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI::Init();
    int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
    int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
    char name[256];
    int len;
    MPI::Get_processor_name(name, len);

    printf("Hi I'm %s:%d\n", name, rank);

    if (rank == 0) {
        while (size > 1) {
            int val;
            MPI::Status status;
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&val, 1, MPI::INT, MPI::ANY_SOURCE, MPI::ANY_TAG, status);
            int source = status.Get_source();
            printf("%s:0 received %d from %d\n", name, val, source);
            size--;
        }
        printf("all workers checked in!\n");
    }
    else {
        int val = rank + 10;
        printf("%s:%d sending %d...\n", name, rank, val);
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&val, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 0);
        printf("%s:%d sent %d\n", name, rank, val);
    }
    MPI::Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: ompi_info

```
$ ./mpirun --bynode -host A,B --tag-output ompi_info -v ompi full --parsable
[1,0]<stdout>:package:Open MPI user@A Distribution
[1,0]<stdout>:ompi:version:full:1.4.3
[1,0]<stdout>:ompi:version:svn:r23834
[1,0]<stdout>:ompi:version:release_date:Oct 05, 2010
[1,0]<stdout>:orte:version:full:1.4.3
[1,0]<stdout>:orte:version:svn:r23834
[1,0]<stdout>:orte:version:release_date:Oct 05, 2010
[1,0]<stdout>:opal:version:full:1.4.3
[1,0]<stdout>:opal:version:svn:r23834
[1,0]<stdout>:opal:version:release_date:Oct 05, 2010
[1,0]<stdout>:ident:1.4.3
[1,1]<stdout>:package:Open MPI user@B Distribution
[1,1]<stdout>:ompi:version:full:1.4.3
[1,1]<stdout>:ompi:version:svn:r23834
[1,1]<stdout>:ompi:version:release_date:Oct 05, 2010
[1,1]<stdout>:orte:version:full:1.4.3
[1,1]<stdout>:orte:version:svn:r23834
[1,1]<stdout>:orte:version:release_date:Oct 05, 2010
[1,1]<stdout>:opal:version:full:1.4.3
[1,1]<stdout>:opal:version:svn:r23834
[1,1]<stdout>:opal:version:release_date:Oct 05, 2010
[1,1]<stdout>:ident:1.4.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to 1.5.3 on A and installing 1.5.3 on C. I'm not sure whether it was the upgrade, or an issue with B, but everything is working now.

For reference:

- original setup: node A (arch linux, Open MPI 1.4.3), node B (ubuntu, Open MPI
  1.4.3)
- working setup: node A (arch linux, Open MPI 1.5.3), node C (arch linux,
  Open MPI 1.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this is that something is not set up properly on the remote host; it could be login/network problems, or that the MPI libraries/executables or the program itself isn't found on the remote host.

What happens if you try

```
mpirun -np 2 -host A,B  hostname
```

?

Comment: Ok, so that probably rules out simple network issues; now how about a trivial MPI hello world program:  #include <mpi.h> int main() { MPI::Init(); int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(); int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size(); printf("Hi from %d of %d\n", rank, size); MPI::Finalize(); return 0; }

Comment: Hi from 0 of 2
Hi from 1 of 2

Comment: Ok, then I think the most likely option is different versions of MPI installed on the different machines.   What is your MPI installation on A, and B?  Are they in the same locations?

Comment: They are both version 1.4.3. I've posted the output of ompi_info above. A is running arch linux and B is running ubuntu. Thanks for your help so far!